# Selenium cannot locate chrome webdriver in AWS Lambda: "errorMessage": "Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

My uploaded .zip file has the following contents: lambda_function.py bs4 selenium certifi

I can see that within selenium is the webdriver folder, and within the webdriver folder is the chrome folder. I am using v4.11.2 of selenium, which is noted as compatible with Python 3.7+, and I am using Lambda's Python 3.8 runtime. Some other versions of this question seem to have been answered by simplifying the invocation of `driver = webdriver`... however, nothing that I've tried or found so far has worked for me. I have tried with and without various options setting, but right now I'm simply calling `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Note that this is all occurring after various successful import statements at the top of lambda_function.py:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium.common import exceptions
from time import sleep

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    driver = Chrome()
```

Stacktrace:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location\n",
  "errorType": "NoSuchDriverException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 33, in lambda_handler\n    driver = Chrome()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 45, in __init__\n    super().__init__(\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py\", line 51, in __init__\n    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py\", line 41, in get_path\n    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete 1) code trials 2) complete error stacktrace

Comment: I updated with the stacktrace and the line that is actually causing the error

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation URL provided in error stacktrace:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

Optimal solution may be to specify path to driver.
Example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
...
...
webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/path/to/chromedriver')
```

Comment: It's still not working. I placed the chromedriver into the bin folder, so my file structure looks like: lambda_function.py bs4 certifi selenium bin and called `driver = Chrome(service=Service('/bin/chromedriver'))`. But I still get "NoSuchDriverException".

Comment: Would the path I mentioned above be sufficient or would I need to reference the entire directory (`/myProjectName/bin/chromedriver`)?

Comment: @slothish1 `bin` folder is probably under `opt` folder, so use: 
`service = Service(executable_path=r'/opt/bin/chromedriver')`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)`

Comment: For the options:
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
`options.add_argument('--headless')`
`options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')`